# error because of missing object in signalslot (tx_news)

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, tx-news

i wrote a signalslot extension for tx_news which extends the detailAction. The dispatcher works as expected when a news in detail view is called. But when the detail page is called without valid parameters for a existing news entry i get the following error:

```
Oops, an error occurred!
Argument 1 passed to .....\Slots\NewsControllerSlot::detailActionSlot() must be an instance of GeorgRinger\News\Domain\Model\News, null given
```

The error is easy to understand:

```
public function detailActionSlot(News $newsItem, $currentPage, $demand, $settings, $extendedVariables)
```

the first parameter $newsItem is missing.

But how can i avoid the error? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David Bruchmann gave me a hint:

```
public function detailActionSlot(News $newsItem = null, $currentPage, $demand, $settings, $extendedVariables)
{
    if (is_object($newsItem)) { 
        // do stuff here
   }
}
```

works perfectly even the 404 is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Create a pr on github or at least an issue, this is a bug

Comment: Thank you Georg, i made an issue at github. But it seems that it is simply an error of me ...